# Tableau - How check if a value equals a value from another row and column

Tags: tableau-api

I have the following table:

```
+------------+--------------+---------+---------+---------+
|  Category  |  Subcategory |FruitName|  Date1  |  Date2  |
+------------+--------------+---------+---------+---------+
|     A      |       1      |   Foo   |   2011  |   2017  |
|            |              +---------+---------+---------+
|            |              |Pineapple|   2011  |   2013  |
|            |              +---------+---------+---------+
|            |              |  Apple  |   2017  |   2018  |
|            +--------------+---------+---------+---------+
|            |      2       |  Peach  |   2014  |  2015   |
|            |              +---------+---------+---------+
|            |              |  Orange |   2015  |  2018   |
|            |              +---------+---------+---------+
|            |              |  Banana |   2009  |  2013   |
+------------+--------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I'd like to display the fruit names where `Date1` from one row == `Date2` from another row, but only if they are equals within the same `Subcategory`. In the table above, this filter should retrieve the rows based on those criterias:

[image: Table with results]

And the final table would look like this:

```
+------------+--------------+---------+---------+---------+
|  Category  |  Subcategory |FruitName|  Date1  |  Date2  |
+------------+--------------+---------+---------+---------+
|     A      |       1      |   Foo   |   2011  |   2017  |
|            |              +---------+---------+---------+
|            |              |  Apple  |   2017  |   2018  |
|            +--------------+---------+---------+---------+
|            |      2       |  Peach  |   2014  |  2015   |
|            |              +---------+---------+---------+
|            |              |  Orange |   2015  |  2018   |
+------------+--------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

How can I possibly achieve this?

Comment: Couldn't understand the requirement, honestly very confusing. Explain a bit more

Answer (score 2):

Your logic provided doesnot match with the output provided. If you are after the output, your logic should be:

```
SELECT f1.* from fruits f1 JOIN fruits f2 
ON f1.Subcategory=f2.Subcategory 
WHERE f1.Date1=f2.Date2 OR f1.Date2 = f2.Date1;
```

If your data source supports custom SQL, you can straight away use the above query. If not you can still achieve it in Tableau using a Full Outer Join and a calculated Field.(Tableau doesn't support OR condition in Joins.)

1. Create a self full outerjoin with the following criteria
   [image]
2. Create a calculation called 'FILTER' as below
   [image]
3. Apply a datasource filter to keep only 'FILTER' = True
   [image]
4. Hide Fields from the rightside connection and you will have the required output.
   [image]

Comment: I will give a try with your solution. In the meanwhile I also updated my question by adding an image to explain the output I am looking for (since it is correct). I probably explained wrongly what I was looking for.